# How to implement a procedure that permits an object to know states of brotherhood?

Tags: oop, boolean

I wonder how to implement in OOP a procedure that an object could have.

Say I have a lot of dogs.
I need for each dog, a bark ratio.

```
Dog dog_a = new Dog()
Dog dog_b = new Dog()
Dog dog_c = new Dog()
```

At start, each bark ratio is 0.

```
dog_a.bark()
```

Then for *dog_a* bark ratio is 1;1.
respectively, *dog_b* and *dog_c* bark ratio is 0;1.

```
dog_b.bark()
```

Then for *dog_a* and *dog_b* bark ratio is 1;3.

I need a ratio **procedure**.

At this time `dog_c.ratio()` returns 0;3.

See ?

I'm working on a spectrum based boolean optimization procedure.
My objects are all NAND.
They are to implement each a self spectrum analysis of outputs.

I was sendind a CLK equivalent to count for output ability of change.
But I now want to do it async'

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C# for rapid testing, c++ later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done in C with a next() equivalent statement that includes a counter.